# How to get WordPress blog name in custom emails

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I use wp_mail to send out custom emails. All works great but I can't get the blog name via shortcode within the email body.

Seriously? Yes... I'm afraid so.

I have tried:

```
function yl_blog_name_shortcode() {
    return get_bloginfo('name');
}
add_shortcode('yl_blog_name','yl_blog_name_shortcode');



function yl_blog_name_shortcode() {
    return get_option('blogname');
}
add_shortcode('yl_blog_name','yl_blog_name_shortcode');
```

But nothing...

You would say this is a way too easy question right? Well, every time I only get the actual [yl_blog_name] shortcode as text in stead of the BLOG NAME.

I think I need to add a global or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use do_shortcode() function. You should use [shortcode] only in text editors or text widgets of Wordpress, but not in any code. If you want to use shortcode in PHP code, you should use do_shortcode() function.

Comment: I understand your point. The problem though is that I have an option page (created with ACF) where you can compose your own email subject and body. So I need the shortcodes to be ready to add them in the text and textarea fields [like_this].